# ORACLE SQL - ALTER TABLE ORDER BY

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sas

I have a table with two columns "COL_A" and "COL_B" which I create by inserting one row at a time:

```
COL_A       COL_B
20200330    49
20200413    31
20200420    19
20200511    99
20190318    73
20190401    86
```

I would like at the end of the program to have the table ordered by COL_A. I thought this coud be possible by running an `ALTER TABLE` command after I filled the table so I tried with:

```
PROC SQL;
     CONNECT TO ORACLE (USER=XXX ORAPW=XXX PATH=XXX);
          EXECUTE (
                ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE 
                ORDER BY COL_A

    ) BY ORACLE;
    DISCONNECT FROM ORACLE;
QUIT;
```

But I get

```
ERROR: ORACLE execute error: ORA-01735: opción ALTER TABLE no válida.
```

Of course I could create another table with the data of this original table ordered by COL_A, but I would like to know if I can do it in place.

I am using ORACLE SQL in SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can only order the table when you are querying the data:

```
select t.*
from schema.table t
order by t.col_a;
```

If you are concerned about performance, you can add an index on `(col_a)` -- so the index is used instead of actually sorting.

Note:  The lack of ordering is also true of views.  If you want an ordered result set, you need to use `order by` in the query.

Comment: Thank you. I have little knowledge of db. So I understand there is no way to do it in place as I intented and that I should create another table/view with your command to get the desired output, correct?

Comment: There is nothing to "create". The data will not be stored in order. It will only be sorted when you select it for use, using whatever "order by" clause you specify at the time. Technically you _could_ include an "order by" clause in a view definition, but this is generally considered a bad practice (what if you wanted to change the order?).

Comment: It is _fundamental_ to relational database theory that rows in a table are UNordered.  They are like balls in a basket.  As others have pointed out, you get them in a given order by use of the ORDER BY clause when you SELECT them.  There is zero point in even attempting to force them into some given order within the table itself.

Comment: @Ale . . . I understand that this can be confusing coming from the SAS world where datasets are ordered.  This does allow SQL to more easily scale and implement a wider variety of algorithms for processing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different things:

1.If you want to order the result in your PROC_SQL process

```
 proc sql;
         CONNECT TO ORACLE (USER=XXX ORAPW=XXX PATH=XXX);
              EXECUTE (
                    SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE 
                    ORDER BY COL_A
    
        ) BY ORACLE;
        DISCONNECT FROM ORACLE;
    quit;
```

By the way, you may want to use LIBNAME in SAS to connect to Oracle, thereby you don't need to build the connect everytime.

2.Run a DDL statement. There is no such thing as ALTER TABLE xxxx ORDER BY . for Ordering columns in Oracle you have indexes.

```
proc sql;
  CONNECT TO ORACLE (USER=XXX ORAPW=XXX PATH=XXX);
  execute(CREATE INDEX SCHEMA.YOUR_INDEX_NAME ( COL_A ) on SCHEMA.TABLE ) BY ORACLE;
quit;
```

However, **I believe it is a very very bad practice to use SAS for running DDL statements.** If you want to order the results, just order the query. Besides, running DDL statements requires that the user connecting by SAS is granted with the right privileges, which normally in any company in the world it shouldn't be possible. Keep in mind that you use SAS for analytical purposes, therefore your DBA normally will grant only read privileges to the user who connect by SAS.

Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply like the example shown below, refer https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-order-by to know variations in it.

```
SELECT
    name,
    address,
    credit_limit
FROM
    customers
ORDER BY
    name ASC;
```